# def myfunction(silent = False, x, y) what does the part "silent = False" do?

Tags: python, function, arguments

In the python code for function when one sets something like:

```
def myfunction(silent=False, x, y)
```

What does `silent=False` do?

Comment: You can't have a function set up like this, you will need to change it to `def myfunction(x, y, silent=False),`

Comment: This is called a keyword arguement, or more commonly, kwarg. Have a read of any basic python tutorial.

Comment: @Hamish: your description is wrong in a few ways.  Keyword arguments are done by the caller.  `silent` here can be provided positionally, and `x` can be provided as a keyword.  And "kwarg" is a different thing, used with `**`.

Comment: I recommend to read the [official Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial), then you would find [4.7.1. Default Argument Values](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

Answer (score 6):

With your current code:

```
def myfunction( silent = False, x, y)
```

The following error will be raised:

```
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

If you change it to:

```
def myfunction(x, y, silent=False)
```

`silent` uses its default value of `False` if it is not passed as a parameter eg. `myfunction(x, y)` will be the equivalent of `myfunction(x, y, False)`

Comment: Maybe OP found some code using Py3k keyword only arguments. `def myfunction(silent=False, *, x, y):` and forgot to write the `*`

Comment: Soo the actual correct answer is "stops the function from compiling" ;)

Comment: @JBernado Doesn't look like something the OP would be trying.

Comment: @Voo Yes but I'm guessing that the OP meant something else and created the example on the spot.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, you have to have `silent` as the last parameter.  This defines `silent` as an optional parameter to your function. If the caller doesn't provide a value, the default of `False` will be used.

Once you define a function this way:

```
def myfunc(x, y, silent=False):
```

you have a function called `myfunc` that can be called two different ways:

```
myfunc(1, 2, True)
myfunc(1, 2)
```

In both calls, x will be 1 and y will be 2.  In the first call, `silent` will be True.  In the second, `silent` will be False.

Comment: I truly appreciate all answers especially Ned's and Jamylak's. I agree that 'silent' should be placed as the last parameter. I agree as well with the explanation though I was actually just wanting to know if 'silent' is something special in python that it was used on a code by one developer. Is it to suppress the execution of whatever statement following the definition? Co'z if its not something special,then it can just be replaced by any other word I can think of.